# How to "soft delete" user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I currently use Devise for user registration/authentication in a Rails project. When a user wants to cancel their account, the user object is destroyed, which leaves my application in an undesired state.

What is the easiest way to implement a "soft delete", i.e. only removing personal data and marking the user as deleted? I still want to keep all record associations.

I assume I will have to first introduce a new "deleted" column for users. But then I am stuck with this default code in the user's profile view:

```
<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.</p>
```

Where can I find the `:delete` method? How should I overwrite the default Devise methods?

Comment: What should happen when the user is deleted? should all his posts/activity be deleted or what?

Comment: I would like to retain all associations with other objects but just remove personal data (name/e-mail address) and disable login.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I could advise overriding `destroy` method on your User model to simply do `update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)` (instead of actually destroying), but this deviation from standard API could become burdensome in the future, so here's how to modify the controller.

Devise has a bunch of default controllers out of the box. The best way to customize them is to create your own controller inheriting the corresponding devise controller. In this case we are talking about `Devise::RegistrationsController` — which is easily recognized by looking at source. So create a new controller.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

Now we have our own controller fully inheriting all the devise-provided logic. Next step is to tell devise to use it instead of the default one. In your routes you have `devise_for` line. It should be changed to include registrations controller.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

This seems strange, but it makes sense because by default it's 'devise/registrations', not simply 'registrations'.

Next step is to override the `destroy` action in registrations controller. When you use `registration_path(:user), :method => :delete` — that's where it links. To `destroy` action of registrations controller.

Currently devise does the following.

```
def destroy
  resource.destroy
  set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
  sign_out_and_redirect(self.resource)
end
```

We can instead use this code. First let's add new method to `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def soft_delete
    # assuming you have deleted_at column added already
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
  end
end

# Use this for Devise 2.1.0 and newer versions
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def destroy
    resource.soft_delete
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end
end

# Use this for older Devise versions
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def destroy
    resource.soft_delete
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
    sign_out_and_redirect(resource)
  end
end
```

Now you should be all set. Use scopes to filter out deleted users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've been able to cook my own solution with your input!

Comment: Great thanks for the answer! Please fix the typo: **update_attribtue**

Comment: How can I let the user re-signup at a later time with the same email?

Comment: @elsurudo, I found this to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886317/undelete-acts-as-paranoid-deleted-user-on-devise-sign-in

Comment: Make sure to also override the new sessions controller to not allow people to sign in if they've deleted their account.

Comment: A similar example is also on the devise wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account

Answer (score 95):

Adding onto [hakunin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140643/how-to-soft-delete-user-with-devise/5141014#5141014):

To prevent "soft deleted" users from signing in, override `active_for_authentication?` on your `User` model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && !deleted_at
end
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct hook that also kicks out newly deleted users from their current session.

Comment: This is really the best answer. [Here are the docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable).

Comment: Thanks for this, the only part I didn't like was the message being shared with the account not confirmed. See my answer on how to change that message: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14966003/637094

Comment: To add to d_either's reference, it seems like you need to also define inactive_message in addition to active_for_authentication? on your User model.  This is to provide a message for why the active_for_authentication? would return false.

Comment: If you want the same validation message as if the user record was actually not present, you might want to define inactive_message as:
`def inactive_message
  return self.active ? super : I18n.t('devise.failure.not_found_in_database')
end`

Answer (score 10):

You could use [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_paranoid) for your User model, which sets a deleted_at instead of deleting the object.

Comment: I've heard from that one before. How would it interact with Devise? Where would I need to change anything apart from installing `acts_as_paranoid`?

Comment: @shick ...you should add `acts_as_paranoid` line to your User model(or any other model you need soft delete).

Comment: This gem has a lot of forks/versions and I could not find a working one for Rails 3.2.x

Comment: @IvailoBardarov There's a new gem called paranoia for Rails 3: https://github.com/radar/paranoia

Answer (score 7):

A complete tutorial can be found at [Soft Delete a Devise User Account](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account) on the Devise wiki page.

Summary:
1. Add a "deleted_at" DATETIME column
2. Override users/registrations#destroy in your routes
3. Override users/registrations#destroy in the registrations controller
4. Update user model with a soft_delete & check if user is active on authentication
5. Add a custom delete message

Answer (score 0):

```
  def devise_current_user
   @current_user ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :user)
  end

  def current_user
    if params[:user_id].blank?
      devise_current_user
    else
      User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.