# How do I keep a user even after they've been deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Let's say I have a user created, who leaves some comments on my site, and then I delete them using @user.destroy.

Now when I display the comments, it throws up errors because @user is nil for the comments they've written.

What would be a good approach to fixing this, considering that:

- I would still like to be able to delete users (at least superficially)
- I would like the user to be able to be re-signed up using the same credentials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "soft delete" user with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140643/how-to-soft-delete-user-with-devise)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a field called `deleted_at` then define a model method `archive` which populates the `deleted_at` with the current time and saves. Default scope for the model is then `where('deleted_at IS NULL')` (or `where{deleted_at == nil}` if you love [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) like I do).

I use this for much more than my user models. I even have the functionality abstracted away so in each model I want archivable I just do `archived_by :deleted_at` in the model. There are likely places in your app where you have to check and see if the requested record is archived/deleted, but for the most part this is a simple and elegant solution. Bringing a record back from being deleted/archived is as simple as `record.deleted_at = nil` (or `record.archive(false)`/`record.unarchive` if you prefer).

For this to be performant on a large table I recommend indexing the `deleted_at` column.

Comment: I wish i could comment, but in agreement with Carl, here is much of the code you would need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140643/how-to-soft-delete-user-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that is simpler is to put a boolean field called trashable and use a concern to define scopes (as @dhh suggested https://gist.github.com/1015151).

So all you need is to create a controller action that does a @user.trash! (I would put a bang on the trash) and the user is 'soft-deleted'.